# How to get the declaring Type of a Method by MethodSymbol?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to find out the actual Type that defines the method in a sub type. E.g.:

```
typeOf[List[_]].decl(TermName("map")).asMethod.?declaringType?
```

as in Java you can get call `Method::getDeclaringClass` to get the Class that declared the method. How can I achieve this in Scala? I checked both `info` and `typeSignature` and they only contain the method signature but no enclosing class info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
typeOf[List[_]].decl(TermName("map")).asMethod.owner.asType //class List
```

Comment: How to find the methods owner inherited from super class/traits? e.g. `flatten` and `unzip` are inherited from `GenericTraversableTemplate` trait, but `typeOf[List[_]].decl(TermName("map"))` returns None?

Comment: Oh nvm I got it. I can use `member` instead of `decl`... Thanks!